# Having problems creating PHP auto reply form

Tags: php

Im trying to create an 'auto reply' function using PHP.  The send email script works perfectly on it's own but I'm struggling to get it working with my submit form script... any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
        <?php
     $field_subject = $_POST['subject'];
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$email_to = 'aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk';
$email_subject = 'Contact Form Message';

$body_message .= 'Name: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Subject: '.$field_subject."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = "From: $field_email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $field_email\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $body_message, $headers);




if ($mail_status) { 

$to      = '$field_email';
$subject = 'Thanks for contacting me';
$message = 'Thanks for your message, I will get back to you soon!';
$headers = 'From: aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);?>
```

Comment: Perhaps include the form?

Comment: It should like :  $to      = $field_email ; since its a variable.

Comment: Hmm maybe,  i've been using external scripts, would it be better to include the script with the form.? thanks

Comment: perfect!! thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options to do that:

- Header back to the form, at the end of the submit.php, including a parameter so you can show a message on form.php if you like:

`header("Location: form.php?send=success");`

- Header to a special thanks page:

`header("Location: thanks.html");`

- Process the form using javascript. Post the data with a AJAX request and on success, show a success message. (google: [link](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=submit%20form%20using%20jquery))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'send_mail'){

         $field_subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_to = 'aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk';
    $email_subject = 'Contact Form Message';

    $body_message .= 'Name: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Subject: '.$field_subject."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

    $headers = "From: $field_email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $field_email\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $body_message, $headers);




    if ($mail_status) { 

    $to      = '$field_email';
    $subject = 'Thanks for contacting me';
    $message = 'Thanks for your message, I will get back to you soon!';
    $headers = 'From: aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: aaron@aaronstrickland.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

// Your form code here
?>
```

You are using this file as external file.